# Reading the specific json element in un-fixed length group

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to read the specific tag within a JSON file with python that I got from API and if they were fixed, I would have had no problem, but it seems that sometimes the elements jump around I can't go after the "sequence" number, but have to use the name to locate it. The name should stay consistent.

Here are the two types that I have seen so far, but I am sure there could be more variation, so instead of relying on the

heroID = data[count]['player'][0]['data'][8]['number']

to extract the value, I would much rather, look for the location of "HeroID" and read that into it variable.

longer one

```
[
{'id': 'HeroBattleTag', 'string': 'TFYoDa#1456'}, 
{'id': 'GameAccount', 'number': 10519139}, 
{'id': 'HeroClass', 'string': 'monk'}, 
{'id': 'HeroGender', 'string': 'f'}, 
{'id': 'HeroLevel', 'number': 70}, 
{'id': 'ParagonLevel', 'number': 1212}, 
{'id': 'HeroClanTag', 'string': 'Sc'}, 
{'id': 'ClanName', 'string': 'Super CasuaI'}, 
{'id': 'HeroId', 'number': 95443875}
]
```

shorter one

```
[
{'id': 'HeroBattleTag', 'string': 'Michael#1920'}, 
{'id': 'GameAccount', 'number': 96532923}, 
{'id': 'HeroClass', 'string': 'monk'}, 
{'id': 'HeroGender', 'string': 'f'}, 
{'id': 'HeroLevel', 'number': 70}, 
{'id': 'ParagonLevel', 'number': 1062}, 
{'id': 'HeroId', 'number': 95441675}
]
```

Comment: So iterate over the list until you find the dict with an `id` set to what you want. Exactly what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: It's nested within another array, if I am already iterating over a header level, should I be able to iterate under the child level?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't you? if you've got code and it's not working as you expect, please show it and describe what it's doing.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to loop through element within an element. My current code loops through the main data, element, but I am not sure how I can loop through the internal json element 

     #while count <300:
    #    for i in data:
    #        character = []
    #        rank = data[count]['order']   #ladderRank
    #        accountId = data[count]['player'][0]['accountId'] #accountID
    #        heroID = data[count]['player'][0]['data'][8]['number'] #heroID
    #        riftLevel = data[count]['player'] #rift Level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question was flawed from beginning, but I was able to write the code by building an iteration over a child json record, while already iterating over the parent one.

```
count = 0
for i in data:
    character = []
    rank = data[count]['order']   #ladderRank
    accountId = data[count]['player'][0]['accountId'] #accountID
    c = 0
    for k in data[count]['player'][0]['data']:
        if k['id'] == 'HeroId':
            heroID = k['number'] 
            pprint.pprint(heroID)
            break
        else: 
            c = c + 1
            if c > len(data[0]['player'][0]['data']):
                break
```